# Attributes and Partial Classes

Tags: winforms

I'm wondering if it is possible to find classes that have an attribute that is on the partial class implementation?  Such that:

```
public class Test {
}

[Attribute()]
public partial class Test {
}
```

I cannot put the attribute on the original class because it is a Form.

Comment: No, that detail disappears after the C# compiler is done with it.  Putting an attribute on a Form derived class is not a problem, nobody can guess why you are looking for a workaround.

Comment: I want a work around because the Form derived class is autogenerated.  If I were to add the attribute there then it will disappear after the form is generated again.  If there is a way to see that the partial class inherits an interface that will work too.